# Document Scanner, CanoScan N650U not reconised

Tags: scanner

I have tried the scan feature in Libre Office, downloaded a couple of scanners and nothing.

The "Nothing" actually means just that, the Scanners plugged in to a USB port, none of the software is detecting that a scanner imaging device is attached and one scanner software is complaining about dependencies and requires some other software to be present...

The several threads I have looked at on here and other sites don't address the problem of the device not being detected.

Suggestions please on what to do to sort this problem out please.

Comment: What scanning software have you downloaded/tried? SimpleScan, which  is included with the OS?

Comment: I have tried downloading all that is on offer. Not one piece of software picks up the device. Only thing I can think of is to install WINE but the last time I tried that back in 2009, I distinctly remember that it wouldn't install the drivers for the scanner.

Comment: gscan2pdf suddenly now runs without crashing and it detects the scanner but then decides that theirs an I/O error in a pop up message.

Comment: gscan2pdf now doesn't work but the Simple Scan now works and two of the three image viewers bundled with now don't work, that the shotwell, not that shotwell has ever done anything useful, the image Magic(?) hacn't worked properly. Given up trying to figure out why and what.

Comment: On LinuxMint (similar to ubuntu), `sane` and `libsane` were installed by default, but I had to install `libsane-extras` to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to download every imaging, camera & editor software on offer, I still don't know which piece of software added the missing library but the scanner now works, the software intermittently crashes, well most of the software crashes, however I did eventually get the paperwork scanned and emailed.

So this question can now be closed.